# React-Native Modal does not show when Dom rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog

In my render function,I make a request,so 'loading' will show when loading.After received the data ,I called 'setState' to make the DOM rerender. I want to show the modal,but the modal do not present. What' wrong with me?

```
 render: function() {

    if (!this.props.data) {
           return (<View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <Text>loading</Text>
                </View>);
    }
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, width:screenWidth}}>
         <Modal
                visible={true}
                transparent={true}
                onRequestClose={()=>{
                }}
                onShow={()=>{
                }}>
                <View
                    style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'}}>
                    <View style={{height:200,width:275,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                        <Button title='confirm' onPress={()=>{}}/>
                        <Button title='cancel' onPress={()=>{}}/>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check condition in single return like:

```
render(){
    return(
        {(!this.props.data) 
        ? (<View style={{flex:1}}>
              <Text>loading</Text>
          </View>)
        : (<View style={{flex:1, width:screenWidth}}>
            <Modal/> { /*your modal code */}
        </View>)
        }
    );
}
```

First check your modal opens without condition or not, if yes then it is style or re-rending issue.

Comment: @Eric have you got is fixed?

Comment: I got an error,'Unexpected token'. Maybe '?:' can not use in the return function?

Comment: You can use ternary condition in return, I have used in almost every page

Comment: Failed to load source: Error Domain=JSServer Code=500 "SyntaxError XXX.js: Unexpected token (583:13)" ,The code "({!this.props.data)"  at line 583.

Comment: I have used  ternary condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148581/discussion-between-jigar-shah-and-eric).